# JavaScript design patterns

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

This is a question for general discussion. Are there any good, comprehensive resources for useful JavaScript design patterns. I am trying to avoid references that attempt to coerce JavaScript into, say, Java by imposing patterns more suited to another language. Let's let JS be JS and shape our patterns around the strengths.

Please any discussion would be valued by more than just me, I suspect.

Comment: The best resource for useful Javascript design patterns is stackoverflow.com

Comment: [In response](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to your first sentence: " **This is not a discussion board**, this is a place for questions that can be answered!" Regardless, it's a good question, +1.

Comment: This should probably be "community wiki".

Answer (score 23):

Here's an on-line resource:

[**Essential JavaScript Design Patterns For Beginners**](http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/)

Answer (score 11):

Here's a good one:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

This is an awesome book by O'Reilly. It builds on their "JavaScript: The Good Parts".

[image]

It references a lot of the patterns mentioned in the "Gang of Four" book and notes a lot of the problems solved in that book are trivial to solve with JavaScript.

Comment: stoyan stefanov is kinda smart.

Answer (score 8):

APress has a book called "Pro Javascript Design Patterns" that is probably just what you're looking for.  While the author (Diaz Harmes) is certainly not "the gang of four", I think he does a pretty good job; I know I learned quite a bit from it (and it got 4.5 stars on Amazon).

Amazon link: [http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Design-Patterns-Recipes-Problem-Solution/dp/159059908X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/159059908X)

[image]

Comment: "I am trying to avoid references that attempt to coerce JavaScript into, say, Java by imposing patterns more suited to another language."

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure why no one has listed this, but Addy Osmani's JavaScript design pattern book is fantastic and freely available online.  He really digs deep to show you the nuts and bolts of each pattern.

http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/

Comment: This is already suggested in the first answer

Answer (score 3):

- [Peter Michaux](http://peter.michaux.ca/) has some decent articles
- Also see [Crockford's](http://javascript.crockford.com/) articles (and [his book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742))
- A new book on the subject by Stoyan Stefanov: [Object-Oriented JavaScript: Create scalable, reusable high-quality JavaScript applications and libraries](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847194141)

Comment: Crockford's stuff is one of the better resources on patterns in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the best design patterns resources I've found for JavaScript
http://shichuan.github.com/javascript-patterns/

It's aimed for JavaScript as we know and not necessarily trying only use concepts of other languages.