# Application based on Prototypical inheritance in real life projects

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, inheritance, prototype-programming, prototypal-inheritance

Class-based inheritance shows its usefulness in creating big programming systems, especially GUI systems.

How can be applied Prototypical-based inheritance in real life applications? How we should build system instead of creating classes hierarchies?

Are here exist any programming patterns for **real** prototypical based OOP as exists for class-based OOP?

Answer (score 2):

> **nahab**: Are here exist any programming patterns for real prototypical based OOP as exists for class-based OOP ?

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168805/javascript-design-patterns) should direct you to some good resources on practical Javascript Design Patterns.

> **nahab**: How can be applied Prototypical-based inheritance in real life applications? How we should build system instead of creating classes hierarchies?

See [this list](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaUses) of Lua users (another prototype-based language), taking note of its use in *Adobe Lightroom*.

Comment: I was thinking that no one will answer this question at all :)